# symfony2 addValidator

Tags: symfony-2.2

I have read about how to validate the value of a field depending in the value of another one. But all of these are in symfony2.1 which use the function "isValid()". That is not my case because i am using "validate()" function.

Here is my code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{ 
    $builder->add('type'); 
    $builder->addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form){            

        $validator = new IntegerValidator();                
        $validator->validate($description->getData(),new Integer());

    }));        
}
```

However when i make a submit, i am always getting this error:

```
Call to a member function addViolation() on a non-object in ..\IntegerValidator.php
```

These are the codes of my 2 classes.

```
class IntegerValidator extends ConstraintValidator{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my constraint class

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Integer extends Constraint{
    public $message = 'The string "%string%" contains an illegal character: it can only be an integer.';
}
```

How could i implement this?. Thanks a lot for your help.